# This member function is not getting called, and I can't figure out how to rectify it

Tags: c++

I'm reading through my C++ textbook for an upcoming class, and following along an exercise in the book. This exercise compiles and seems to give the results that you would expect, but it seems there is an error though, and I can't figure out how to fix it.
Here is the code.

```
// Page 706 from text


//Contents of ThisExample.h
class Example
{
    int x;
    public:
        Example(int a){x=a;}
        void setValue(int);
        void printAddressAndValue();

};

/* 
//Contents of ThisExample.cpp
#include "ThisExample.h"

*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


/*********************************************************
 * Set value of object.
*********************************************************/

void Example::setValue(int a)   // <---------- Doesn't execute
{                               // <---------- Doesn't execute
    x = a;                      // <---------- Doesn't execute
}                               // <---------- Doesn't execute

void Example::printAddressAndValue()
{
    cout<< "The object at address " << this << " has "
        << "value "<< (*this).x<<endl;

}

/*
//Contents of main program

#include <iostream>
#include "ThisExample.h"
using namespace std;
*/
int main()
{
    Example ob1(10), ob2(20);
    // Print the addresses of the two objects
    cout<<"Addresses of objects are "<< &ob1 << " and "<<&ob2<<endl;

    // Print the addresses and values from within the member function
    ob1.printAddressAndValue();
    ob2.printAddressAndValue();

    return 0;

}
```

In the book, they talk about replacing

```
void Example::setValue(int a)  
{                               
    x = a;                     
}
```

with

```
void Example::setValue(int a)  
{                               
    this->x = x;                     
}
```

But when I step through it with a debugger (which I am also new to), I don't see that function ever getting called.

I've tried commenting out the function entirely and it still runs, that's how I know it isn't getting called.

I also tried removing from the class

```
    Example(int a){x=a;}
```

but then it doesn't compile.  Any help? I just want to move along with the textbook, which is called "Starting Out With C++ Early Objects
Judy Walters, Godfrey Muganda, Tony Gaddis" and the exercise is on page 706.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain exactly where or when you expect `setValue` to be called? In the code shown, there is no cause for it to be called, so it's normal that it is not called.

Comment: *but it seems there is an error though,* Why?  What makes you think that `setValue` must be called?

Comment: You are not calling a member function anywhere. In your main do `ob1.setValue(123);`. The code gets executed inside the `main` function, not the class definition.

Comment: Just to clear member functions **have to be** called explicitly called by doing ob1.setvalue(*some integer*). If a function is not called by `main()` or by any of functions called from `main()`, the function is never executed.

Comment: `void Example::setValue(int a)  
{                               
    this->x = x;                     
}     ` <-- That looks wrong. That would just assign the member `x` the value it already has and the function argument `a` is unused. Are you *sure* that's what your book is saying? Because if it is, I'd say the book has a bug.

Comment: The next part talks about replacing the code inside of the 'setvalue' function, which is not getting called.

Comment: Well, it just kinda seems its a bad exercise. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't ever get called, because you never call it.

The only place that the member variable `x` is set, in this particular example, is in the constructor. And the constructor happens to do so directly, rather than by calling `setValue()`.

You *could* later call `setValue()` to change `x`, but currently you do not.

It's not uncommon to provide functionality that makes sense to be part of the class, even if you're not using that functionality quite yet. Although, unless you're writing a library, you generally wouldn't do too much of writing functionality you don't yet need.

Perhaps later exercises in the textbook involve calling `setValue()`. I would just continue reading and not worry about this.